# Is there any GotFocus event for Excel Cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I get focus into one particular cell, and if that cell contains a value which is less than 2, then the content in that cell should be multiplied by 60.

BTW, I can get focus into one particular cell by using navigation keys, or by clicking on one partiuclar cell or anything.

For example, I got focus into one particular cell which has a value 1.5. Then, my VBA program should automatically convert that cell value with 90 as 60*1.5=90.

I don't know much about programming in Excel. I can't open most of the sites due to company security policies.

Can anyone please help me on this!

Comment: By **GetFocus** do you mean **Select** or perhaps **click on** ??

Comment: @Gary's Student: It could be anything, I may reach by navigating through arrow keys, or by clicking on one particular cell etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you select your cell, this sub will run. *(Technically, everytime you select **any** cell, this will run. But with the statement `If iSect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`, it will not process the remainder of your code.)*

**NOTE: Place this in your worksheet module** *(Not in a standard module)*

You need to set `myCell` to your desired `Range`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim myCell As Range:    Set myCell = ws.Range("A1")
    Dim iSect As Range

    Set iSect = Application.Intersect(Target, myCell)

    'If the selection is not your cell, exit sub
    If iSect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 

            ' Your code here

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer, and K.Davis answer were so helpful to me. I achieved a lot with your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Say the cell in question is cell **B9**.  Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B9 As Range
    Set B9 = Range("B9")
    If Intersect(Target, B9) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        If B9 < 2 Then B9 = 60 * B9
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer, and K.Davis answer were so helpful to me. Since I can mark just one post as answer, I marked K.Davis one as I achieved even more with his solution. I have given upvote to you.